# transpose csv automatically

Tags: csv, automation, transpose

I have data in narrow format like so:

```
Name; Rob;
Age;  23
Date; 23.05.2000
```

I want to tarsnpose it to wide format automatically:

```
Name; Age; Date;
Rob;  23;  23.05.2000;
```

That's possible if i just copy the first view and paste it with the transpose option. But how can i do that automatically ?

Thanks for help a lot

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases/tag/v1.0.1).  It has a number of very useful commands to make transforming CSVs without code very easy, like [**transpose**](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#transpose).  It's pre-built for a number of modern platforms, so download and go!

I got rid of the extra spaces between fields in your sample:

```
Name;Rob
Age;23
Date;23.05.2000
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export GOCSV_DELIMITER=';'  # GoCSV expects a comma (',') by default
gocsv transpose file.csv
```

and I get:

```
Name;Age;Date
Rob;23;23.05.2000
```

GoCSV expects

Comment: Hi! I'm a little confused... which other people? Your question was very much about what you were trying to do, *I have data*, *I want to transpose it*, ... Are you trying to solve a problem for yourself, or for others? If it is indeed for others your question needs to reflect that. If you're concerned about other people who find your question and my answer, well... that's what StackOverflow is for :) It's up to them to decide what they can and want to do.

Comment: Do you just input the command in Command Prompt ? I get error messages when i copy paste it

Comment: You need to follow the first link, select the installer for your machine, download and install.